# Haskell: How to sum a list of functions?

Tags: haskell

I want to use recursion in Haskell. I define:

```
pf:: Int -> Int
pf 1 = 1
pf n = pf 1 + sum[pf 1..pf n-1]
```

But the sum is not correct! What is the proper way to sum a list of functions?

Comment: The list you're summing consists of `Int`s, not functions. It's also not clear what you want to achieve, i.e. what you want "correct" to be.

Comment: Also note that `pf n-1` means `(pf n)-1`, **not** `pf (n-1)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[pf 1..pf (n-1)]` is not the same as `[pf 1, pf 2, pf 3, ..., pf (n-1)]`.

```
> let f x = 2^x
> [f 1 .. f 4]
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
> [f 1, f 2, f 3, f 4]
[2,4,8,16]
```

You probably want `map`:

```
pf n = pf 1 + sum (map pf [1..n-1])
```

And, just as a remark, `pf x = 2^(x-1)`.

Comment: @CharlieVictor Then mark the answer as “accepted”, and we will all live happily ever after :)

Comment: @CharlieVictor Just click on the check box outline to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the accepted answer, we can do the following refinement

```
pf n = pf 1 + sum (map pf [1..n-1])
```

We sum pf 1 with a sum, then its just a sum
The usual sum can be express using fold as follow

```
sum = fold (+) 0
```

Here 0 can be view as the seed of the sum, to convince you enter the two following expression in ghci

```
foldl (+) 10 [1..10] -- return 65
10 + sum [1..10]    -- return 65 too
```

In our example the seed is equal to **pf 1**, which lead us to

```
pf n = foldl (+) (pf 1) (map pf [1..n-1])
```

Again we can rewrite a term, this time I will focus on list range [1..n-1]

```
enumFromTo 1 (n-1) = [1..n-1]
```

Or n-1 could be rewrite (again) as pred n, then we have

```
enumFromTo 1 (pred n) = [1..n-1]
```

Substituting in the main expression, we obtain

```
pf n = foldl (+) (pf 1) (map pf (enumFromTo 1 (pred n)))
```

Now we can express the main expression in point free style

```
pf = foldl (+) (pf 1) . map pf . enumFromTo 1 . pred
```

We can do more considering than map could be express in term of fold, but for sure we will lost in readability, just note that

```
map f = foldl (\x xs -> f x : xs) []
```

Comment: `map f = foldr ...`, not foldl.